# RGB LED and compatible drivers

Tags: rgb

I need some help regarding LED chips and compatible drivers.

I previously included too little detail and spec's so here it is. I have a 50w RGB chip, voltages are red 16-20, green 24-28, and blue 24-28, it requires 350mA constant current.

I also have a 50W driver that is for warm white LED, the driver is 30-36v and runs at 1.5A, so it drives too high an amperage. I'm wanting to know if I can run RGB chip on such driver, and if a device such as buck or step down will let me do this, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably should go back and update your original question with the new data instead.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "not without additional hardware."

You're better off getting a dc power source and building your own current limiter, or getting appropriate drivers for your the channels.

A lm350 plus heat sink plus set resistor can make for a cheap current limiter. At 350 mA you need at least a 0.5W rated resistor.